# How to include variables from cdn into Karma - jasmine

Tags: gruntjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to run my Karma tests using grunt.
I have an outer variable that is imported to the my application with in the index.html file (In this case, its my Faye variable)
For instance, i need to include this script in order to get the Faye variable:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"
>         src="http://localhost:9292/client.js">
> </script>
> ```

Everything is working as expected when i serve the application(using --force) but my tests fails because phantom cannot find the Faye variable.

How do i include it to karma / phantom so it will recognize my variable?